# Magento 1 to 2 data migration issue: "cart price rules" are missing website and group selection from Magento 1

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

After migrating data from magento 1.6.2 to magento 2.3.2 the shopping cart price rules are missing the website and groups selection.

[image]

For some reason the first 4 shopping cart price rules are not affected by this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem resulted from the difference between website ID, customer group in your Source site and Target site